# How do I create a full-width bar on a web page?

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS defining the style for a `<div>` element in my HTML:

```css
#nav {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #3E6ECE;
}
```

However, for some reason, the page is rendering with a white border as is shown in the image below:

[image: Full-Width Navbar Problems]

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?  How can I get the blue bar to go the full width of the window?

---

For reference, my HTML structure is included below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Header stuff -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='nav'></div>

        <!-- Other body stuff -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try removing padding+margin on the body element

Comment: Yeah, just realized that moments after posting this.